# Mi conexión a base de datos en Android Studio funciona en mi computadora, pero no en mi celular

Tags: php, android-studio, base-de-datos

La aplicación que estoy haciendo funciona sobre Android studio y el emulador de celular, pero no en mi celular, además en mi celular no me muestra ningún mensaje de error

Este es mi código en Android

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView texto;
    Button mostrar;
    RequestQueue rq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        texto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.xtv);
        mostrar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbt);

        mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarServicio("http://192.168.56.1/develorperu/consultarUsuario.php");
            }
        });
    }

    private void ejecutarServicio(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                texto.setText("");
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        texto.append("\n" + object.getString("Nombre") + " " + object.getString("Correo") + " " + object.getString("Nacimiento") + " " + object.getString("Contraseña"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        texto.setText(e.getMessage()+"\nError1");
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                texto.setText(error.getMessage()+"\nError2");
            }
        });
        rq=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        rq.add(request);
    }
}
```

Este es mi código conexion.php

```
<?php

$hostname='localhost';
$database='prueba';
$username='root';
$password='';

$conexion=new mysqli($hostname,$username,$password,$database);

if ($conexion -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Conexion fallida";
}

?>
```

Este es mi código consultarUsuario.php

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$consulta="select * from usuarios";
$resultado = $conexion -> query($consulta);

while($fila=$resultado -> fetch_array()){
    $usuario[]=array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
}


echo json_encode($usuario);
$resultado -> close();

?>
```

En el emulador la aplicación muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mientras que en mi celular muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La base de datos que estoy usando está sobre xamp phpmyadmin, solo tiene una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que muestra Android Studio al correr la aplicación en mi celular:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y qué has intentado hacer?

Comment: lo primero que se me ocurre, es que en tu computadora puedes acceder porque está accediendo a recursos locales, tu celular necesitaría que ese servidor de BD esté abierto para que pueda conectarse... si no es el caso, podrías usar alternativas como SQLite, por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente dados los datos podrían ser dos factores:

1. Por una parte cuando haces la llamada a `ejecutarServicio` debería ser `this.ejecutarServicio(...)` puesto que no debemos olvidar que estamos trabajando con java y esto es una clase.
2. Por otra parte estas llamando a un servicio usando tu IP local que, si está configurada para poder ser accesible desde todos los dispositivos dentro de la red, debería funcionar pero no es recomendable y puediera ser la fuente del error.